# Javascript not executing when inserted after page load

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to push an item to a GTM datalayer using an unusual method which is a workaround. I have a messaging service installed on my website. The messaging service creates a div:

`<div class="small-notifications-wrapper"></div>`

Then when an event happens (for example, a payment), the messaging service inserts another div into the page e.g.

`<div class="notification-small notification-type-message"></div>`

In this div is the content of the notification that is pushed to the website. This can happen any time after the user has the page open. The script isn't loaded with the initial load of the page, it is only inserted when the event occurs later.

I've added a script tag in here e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function dataLayerPush(){dataLayer.push({event:"workflowStep",workflowName: "deposit",workflowStepNumber: 1,workflowStepName: "depositReceived",workflowCompleteFlag: 1,transactionId: "123"})};dataLayerPush();</script>
```

The script populates the dataLayer correctly when I run it in the console, but it doesn't run when the message appears and the div is inserted

I've tried inserting the function directly, and then calling it, but neither way seems to work.

Comment: You're mentioning an event. Have you considered using an event listener to trigger the data layer function?

Comment: How are you inserting the div + script tag?

Comment: I'm using a CRM platform which is in turn using https://pusher.com/ to push the notification into the page